# php include content not loading, possible hash tag/address issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, hashtag

http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

I'm trying to get the above script to work, but with some changes. I need the content to load as php includes, and not as an html string. My main problem right now is that i don't think the code is directing to the right page, thus no new content.

php:

```
switch($_GET['page'])  {
    case 'code' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'mysite/code.php'); break;
    case 'design' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'mysite/design.php'); break;
    case 'writing' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'mysite/writing.php'); break;
```

html:

```
<ul id="menu">
         <li><a title="index" href="#index.php" rel="ajax"><span>home</span></a></li>
         <li><a title="code" href="#code.php" rel="ajax"><span>code</span></a></li>
         <li><a title="design" href="#design.php" rel="ajax"><span>design</span></a></li>
         <li><a title="illustration" href="#illustration.php" rel="ajax"><span>illustration</span></a></li>
         <li><a title="writing" href="#writing.php" rel="ajax"><span>writing</span></a></li>
         <li><a title="links" href="#links.php" rel="ajax"><span>links</span></a></li>
         <li><a title="about" href="#about.php" rel="ajax"><span>about</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    //Check if url hash value exists (for bookmark)
    $.history.init(pageload);   

    //highlight the selected link
    $('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');

    //Seearch for link with REL set to ajax
    $('a[rel=ajax]').click(function () {

        //grab the full url
        var hash = this.href;

        //remove the # value
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

        //for back button
        $.history.load(hash);   

        //clear the selected class and add the class class to the selected link
        $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        //hide the content and show the progress bar
        $('#content').hide();
        $('#loading').show();

        //run the ajax
        getPage();

        //cancel the anchor tag behaviour
        return false;
    }); 
});


function pageload(hash) {
    //if hash value exists, run the ajax
    if (hash) getPage();    
}

function getPage() {

    //generate the parameter for the php script
    var data = 'page=' + document.location.hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
    $.ajax({
        url: "loader.php",  
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {  

            //hide the progress bar
            $('#loading').hide();   

            //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
            $('#content').html(html);

            //display the body with fadeIn transition
            $('#content').fadeIn('slow');       
        }       
    });
}

    </script>
```

Comment: Why there are triple "case 'code'"? change to "case 'design'" and "case 'writing'"

Comment: Why do you use `case 'code'` three times in a row?

Comment: Also change title+"code" to title="code"

Comment: All cases is 'code', `title+"code"` in the html and data should be: `var data = { page:document.location.hash.replace(/^.*#/, '') }`. Tell us where the problem begins, What's in `$_GET['page']`. Inspect from network tab to know what is coming and post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you sure you get the right path?

```
case 'code' : $page = include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mysite/code.php'); break;
case 'design' : $page = include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mysite/design.php'); break;
case 'writing' : $page = include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mysite/writing.php'); break;
```

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in different environments may has trailing slash or not, so be careful when including files from $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

```
case 'code' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mysite/code.php'); break;
case 'design' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mysite/design.php'); break;
case 'writing' : $page = include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mysite/writing.php'); break;
```

Comment: ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'mysite/code.php');($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mysite/code.php');I was just wondering how are these different? I'll check php.net soon but i usually find it a little over my head.

Comment: i did not have the right path. the comment i was copying had a very strange site structure, which i just assumed was how mine should also. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`include` does not return anything, except true/false to indicate the includes success/failure. Basically it's a lot like `eval()`, except using external files. If your included pages are actually generating output, you'd have to capture it first:

```
ob_start();
include('somepage.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();

return $content;
```

Or, if the includes are generating content and saving it to a variable, then:

```
include('somepage.php');
echo $whatever_var_that_somepage_php_stored_the_content_in;
```

Comment: Actually, if the included script has a 'return' outside of any functions, then the include will return a value.  Zeta uses this feature in its auto-loader.  https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/zetacomponents/trunk/Base/src/base_autoload.php